# Ash MATCH operator (=~)

Tags: linux, bash, ash

I'm trying to fit a script for linux onto my WD world edition drive.

The script is written for Bash (debian) but my WD only runs busybox (with ash). Despite this, I have gotten most functionality in there just from using Google. There is only one operator i have not found a counterpart to, the =~ operator

How can i port the functionality of the =~ operator from the old script to ash?

Script:

```
#! /bin/bash
# posttorrent.sh by Killemov
{
  # Log file, file where we tell what events have been processed.
  LOG_FILE=/var/log/posttorrent.log
  # Username for transmission remote.
  TR_USERNAME="username"
  # Password for transmission remote.
  TR_PASSWORD="password"
  # Get current time.
  NOW=$(date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S)
  # Source directory, should not be changed.
  SRC_DIR="${TR_TORRENT_DIR}/${TR_TORRENT_NAME}"
  # Directory to store the un-compressed files in..
  DEST_DIR="${TR_TORRENT_DIR}/${TR_TORRENT_NAME}/"
  # This parameter string could be passed from Transmission in the future.
  TR_TORRENT_PARAMETER="EXTRACT SLEEP1h"

echo "text"
  if [ -e "$SRC_DIR/keep" ]; then
    TR_TORRENT_PARAMETER="$TR_TORRENT_PARAMETER KEEP"
  fi

  if [ -e "$SRC_DIR/exit" ]; then
    TR_TORRENT_PARAMETER="EXIT"
  fi

  # Actual processing starts here.
  if [[ "$TR_TORRENT_PARAMETER" =~ "EXIT" ]]; then
    echo $NOW "Exiting $TR_TORRENT_NAME" >> $LOG_FILE
    exit 0
  fi
echo "text2"
  if [[ "$TR_TORRENT_PARAMETER" =~ "EXTRACT" ]]; then
    cd $TR_TORRENT_DIR
    if [ -d "$SRC_DIR" ]; then
      IFS=$'\n'
      unset RAR_FILES i
      for RAR_FILE in $( find "$SRC_DIR" -iname "*.rar" ); do
        if [[ $RAR_FILE =~ .*part.*.rar ]]; then
          if [[ $RAR_FILE =~ .*part0*1.rar ]]; then
            RAR_FILES[i++]=$RAR_FILE
          fi
        else
          RAR_FILES[i++]=$RAR_FILE
        fi
      done
      unset IFS

      if [ ${#RAR_FILES} -gt 0 ]; then
        for RAR_FILE in "$(eval \$$RAR_FILES[@])"; do
          unrar x -inul "$RAR_FILE" "$DEST_DIR"
          if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
            echo $NOW "Error unrarring $TR_TORRENT_NAME" >> $LOG_FILE
            transmission-remote -n $TR_USERNAME:$TR_PASSWORD -t$TR_TORRENT_ID --verify --start
            exit 0
          fi
        done
        if [[ ! "$TR_TORRENT_PARAMETER" =~ "KEEP" ]]; then
          SLEEP=$(expr match "$TR_TORRENT_PARAMETER" '.*SLEEP\([0-9a-zA-Z]*\)')
          if [ ${#SLEEP} -gt 0 ]; then
            sleep $SLEEP
          fi
          transmission-remote -n $TR_USERNAME:$TR_PASSWORD -t$TR_TORRENT_ID --remove-and-delete
        fi
        echo $NOW "Unrarred $TR_TORRENT_NAME" >> $LOG_FILE
      fi
    fi
  fi
} &
```

(i had some trouble with indirect references, i hoped i fixed that correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Well for the `$VARIABLE =~ PATERN` you should be able to use the:

```
echo "$VARIABLE" | grep -E PATTERN
```

But I think you will have a little bit of trouble with the arithmetical expressions `i++` as well - if it's implemented, then you still need to use the `i=$(($i + 1))` syntax, if it's not implemented, then the `i=$(expr $i + 1)` syntax.

I presume you're reason for the IFS=$'\n' is to split the find on newlines, but you're probably better off with issuing the find into a temporary file, and then doing a `while read line; do ... done <$tmpfile`,

Additionally, I'm not certain if all versions of busybox ash support arrays, so you may have a problem there as well.

Comment: Yep. i tried running the script, and while it looked fine for 10 mins, when i came back i got spammed with "not found" after the array[i++]lines. As i am not that much of a bash/ash person, i think i'm better off looking for something else, sadly.

Comment: `grep -Eq` is slightly better as it prints nothing.